# How can i update swift variable when c++ callback function triggered

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, swift, objective-c++

I would like to notify swift code whenever something changes or event triggered in my .cpp functions.

I've following structure in my app.

> (.cpp)[.hpp] ->(.mm)[.h] -> .swift

I can handle changeThisString from swift code via :

```
let swiftString = CPPWrapper().MyMethodWrapper()
```

this is okay with button click / viewDidLoad but i would like to update this value whenever i set it up from c++.

If C++ passes new string to swift, it shouldn't wait the button click it should work like listener.

I'll be really glad for any kind of help, thank you.

Example:

**my.cpp:**

```
std::string changeThisString = "";

...

virtual void myCallBack(MyCallBackParam &paramter){
    changeThisString = "I WANT TO SEE THIS MESSAGE ON MY APP!"
}

std::string MyClass::MyMethod() {
    return changeThisString;
}
```

**my.hpp:**

```
#include <string>

class MyClass{
public:
    std::string MyMethod();
};
```

**wrapper.mm**

```
#import "wrapper.h"
#import "my.hpp"

    @implementation CPPWrapper
    
    MyClass myClass;
    
    - (NSString*) MyMethodWrapper {
        NSString* result = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:myClass.MyMethod().c_str()];
        return result;
    }
    @end
```

**Wrapper.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface CPPWrapper : NSObject
-(NSString*) MyMethodWrapper;
@end
```

**.swift**

```
let swiftString = CPPWrapper().MyMethodWrapper()
```

Answer (score 1):

**This is an example of C callback that triggers a Combine notification.**

( Moved on GitHub right here : https://github.com/moosefactory/C-callback-to-Swift )

This example changes a value of a C String in a C Library and displays it in a field in a SwiftUI view.

[image]

You don't need to go through Objective-C.

- The first part is the C Library ( Few changes to make it work with C++ )
- The second part is the C<->Swift class

I think it's nice to have an object that makes the bridge between your C code and your swift application, to remove esoteric syntax from the app code. In this example, the file `MyCLibraryInterface`does the job.

This class is an observable object that will publish the value change using combine, so it goes a bit beyond the question - You can stop there and do what you want once you are in the callback block. Note that we can't catch the swift context in c calls ( no calls to self or variables declared on the heap )

- The third part is a simple SwiftUI app that receive change and update interface

**C Library**

- MyCLibrary.h

```c
#ifndef MyCLibrary_h
#define MyCLibrary_h

#include <stdio.h>
#include <dispatch/dispatch.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


/// The callback to call when the string is changed
typedef void callback_t(const char* string);

void setCallBack(callback_t _callback);

/// A function that will change the string
void setString(const char* string);

void startTimer(void);

void cancelTimer(void);

#endif /* MyCLibrary_h */
```

- MyCLibrary.c

```c
#include "MyCLibrary.h"

const char* myString;

dispatch_queue_t queue;
dispatch_source_t timer;
bool running;

callback_t* callback;

void setCallBack(callback_t _callback) {
    callback = _callback;
}

void setString(const char* string) {
    myString = string;
    callback(myString);
}

/// A function that will start a timer that changes string

int ticks = 0;

void idle(dispatch_source_t timer)
{
    ticks++;
    char ticksStr[32];
    sprintf(ticksStr, "Time : %ds", ticks);
    setString(ticksStr);
}

void startTimer() {
    if (running) { cancelTimer(); sleep(1); }
    
    queue = dispatch_queue_create("timerQueue", 0);

    // Create dispatch timer source
    timer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, queue);

    dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timer, ^{idle(timer);});

    dispatch_source_set_cancel_handler(timer, ^{
        dispatch_release(timer);
        dispatch_release(queue);
    });

    dispatch_time_t start = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0);

    // Set timer
    dispatch_source_set_timer(timer, start, NSEC_PER_SEC, 0);

    ticks = 0;
    running = true;
    dispatch_resume(timer);
}

void cancelTimer() {
    running = false;
    dispatch_source_cancel(timer);
    char ticksStr[32];
    sprintf(ticksStr, "Canceled after %ds", ticks);
    setString(ticksStr);
}
```

**C<>Swift Part**

- MyApp-Bridging-Header.h

```swift
#import "MyCLibrary.h"
```

- MyCLibraryInterface.swift

```swift
import Foundation

class MyCLibraryInterface: ObservableObject {
    @Published var string: String = "This is a string"
    
    static let shared = MyCLibraryInterface()
    
    init() {
        setCallBack { stringPtr in
            let newString = CFStringCreateWithCString(kCFAllocatorDefault, stringPtr, kCFStringEncodingASCII) ?? "" as CFString
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                MyCLibraryInterface.shared.string = newString as String
            }
        }
    }
    
    func setLibString(string: String) {
        string.withCString { stringPointer in
            setString(stringPointer)
        }
    }
    
    func startLibTimer() {
        startTimer()
    }

    func cancelLibTimer() {
        cancelTimer()
    }
}
```

**SwiftUI Sample**

This sample app present the intial string and a button. On click or tap, the `setString` function is called in the CLibrary, the swift callback is called and the view is updated following the `ObservableObject` modification

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var myCLibInterface: MyCLibraryInterface = MyCLibraryInterface.shared
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(myCLibInterface.string).frame(width:150).padding()
            Button("Reset") {
                myCLibInterface.setLibString(string: "C Timer Example")
            }.padding()
            Button("Start Timer") {
                myCLibInterface.startLibTimer()
            }.padding()
            Button("Cancel") {
                myCLibInterface.cancelLibTimer()
            }.padding()
        }.padding(20)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but i already can use tihis way with what i shared, i want to something like observer instead of waiting button click, it should change directly. SetString isn't what i want and using callback thread in c++ via swift is not easy. Thank you anyway.

Comment: The button is just here as an example to trigger the C function. Sorry, I should have give a more specific answer. If you do a timer that increment a counter in the c library, your callback will be called in swift. You will always have to pass a callback anyway. Something like ```myCLibInterface.startTimer() { // Your swift callback }```. And also you don't need the obj-C part. I will replace the 'setString' example by a 'startTimer' when I find some time. Cheers

Comment: I have changed to add a timer that updates the string without user action. If you really want to observe the C string value without calling `setString`, then you should create a timer that observe the string value. But I'm not sure it is a good option.

Comment: Thank you so much, i really apreciate your effort. It's really clear and understandable. I need some modification to be able to adapt it for c++ then according to result i'll approve your answer. Thank you so much again @Moose !

Comment: I'm getting following error: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_setCallBack", referenced from:
      NEW_Swift_NoBuild.MyCLibraryInterface.init() -> NEW_Swift_NoBuild.MyCLibraryInterface in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: I'm actually using a c++ library which has a callback, once i got the callback i would like to change swift strings, that's why i asked the question. But this answer is not directly solution of my problem, but i really thank you so much, for your effort & time. It is really helpful, in this case it's not solving my problem but some other people can be find a solution via your answer thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome Emre :). The error is weird. Did you try from the project I have uploaded to github? It looks like a bridging header problem.

Comment: Yes i've cloned ur project it's working properly & so nice with timer :)


I've added header file to my bridge file actually. 

I'm getting the error cause i'm using c++ core library (not cocoapods or smth.) and it's using ui threads while building it's checks architecture. It should be link error.